# Fortify SCA scripting scanning shell scripts

Tags: fortify

Does HP Fortify Software Code Analyzer perform a code scan against any shell scripting languages; bash, sh, c, k, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify supports C language as per my knowledge.

Here is the example of how to build and scan:

```
 sourceanalyzer -b build_id -clean
 sourceanalyzer -b build_id gcc -c test.c
 sourceanalyzer -b build_id -scan result.fpr
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Fortify does not support shell scripts. The closest support would be scanning python. The bigger question would be why are you wanting to scan shell scripts? The threat surface is pretty small, so there's generally not a huge need to assess them.

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.